# How to force refresh old version of Angular app on Nginx server?

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an Angular app already in production, but I've been adding new functionalities that would render the old version obsolete. The current version users are using has a manual way of updating (through a popup), but I know some users just won't update or bother refreshing the page.

My app is under a Nginx configure server with the following settings:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;                                                           
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;                                                       
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";                                                     
                                                                                                  
server {                                                                                          
    listen 80;                                                                                    
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;                          
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;                                                  
}                                                                                                 
                                                                                                  
server {                                                                                          
    listen 8000;                                                                                  
                                                                                                  
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;                          
                                                                                                  
    root /var/www/mysite-front/dist;                                               
    index index.html index.htm;                                                                   
                                                   
    location / {
        expires -1;                                                                          
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.(html)$ { 
        expires -1;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header strict-transport-security "max-age=31536000";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }                                                                                            
    location ~ \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }                                                                                              
    location ~ /\.ht {                                                                            
        deny  all;                                                                                
    }                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
   # add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';           
}
```

My problem is that regardless if I upload a new version, users that don't update, or refresh, keep seeing the old version. Even if I clear the dist folder on the serve, users can keep using the old version of the app.

What could I do to make old users fetch the app straight from the server instead of them relying on whatever cached version they have?